# JSP/Freemarker slow in loading big arraylist

Tags: java, performance, jsp, arraylist, freemarker

I have an ArrayList of objects.

The arraylist has over 200,000 elements.

Iterating through the list in a JSP using struts iterate tag or freemarker using
    *

```
//arround 200 entries in parent
    <#list parent as child>
      <tr>
        <td>${child.id}</td>
        <td>${child.empname}</td>
        <td>${child.tdate}</td>
        <td>${child.leaveid}</td>
       </tr>
    <#list>
   //jsp
   <s:iterate var="child" val="parent">
     <td><s:property val="child.id"></td>
    ........
   </s:iterate>
```

This results in a very slow load time, it takes minutes to load all the elements.

I try looping through the array list in plain java, things are fast, but in jsp and freemarker, looping is slow.

I hope someone helps

Comment: The word you are looking for is **pagination**. And perhaps **lazy-loading**.

Comment: I guess the problem is not with the looping itself. Remove the nested content of `#list` to see. Probably it's not with accessing the child properties either, though you haven't said if you have tried that in Java as well, so it worth trying. Maybe the huge output size (10+ MB-s I guess) is an important factor here. Especially if you look at it in the browser, instead of just downloading it. Or if you have really slow network. Otherwise it should be profiled out... with VisualVM for example. Is the CPU on the server busy at all?

Comment: @ddekany thanks for your response

I have tried looping through in a plain java class [a struts action class] its pretty fast. the server runs in my localhost, only eclipse and the tomcat instant are running. 

I checked the heap size in visual vm, and it runs close to 200 mb

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thanks for the suggestion, i think i should go with paginatiion